# Recursively placing pairs in sublists

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm practicing recursion and am trying to build a function that scans for pairs and puts them in their own list only using recursion (no forEaches, loops, etc).  if there is an odd element, you add a zero.  here is my code and a sample input/output.  The only thing I'm missing is how to handle the undefined case at the end. How would I handle this?

```
function ownListPair(arr){

return arr.length < 2 ? [[arr[0], 0]] : [[arr[0], arr[1]]].concat(ownListPair(arr.slice(2)));

}


var arr = [2,7,8,3,1,4]
//should return [ [ 2, 7 ], [ 8, 3 ], [ 1, 4 ]]
console.log(ownListPair(arr))
//returns [ [ 2, 7 ], [ 8, 3 ], [ 1, 4 ], [ undefined, 0 ] ]
//how do I handle the undefined case? I tried a check for if the length is 1
 and got "maximum call stack exceeded"...
```

also tried a check for arr[0] not being undefined along with the first length check, but also call stack error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a case for `arr.length === 0`. There are a number of ways you can write this, here's one:

```js
function ownListPair(arr){
  if (arr.length === 0)
    return arr;
  else if(arr.length === 1)
    return [[arr[0], 0]];
  else 
    return [[arr[0], arr[1]]].concat(ownListPair(arr.slice(2)));
}

console.log(ownListPair([2,7,8,3,1,4]));
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```